# jdk URL should and how to close?

Tags: java, url, connection

I use `java.net.URL` to fetch html from internet
I set `keepAlive` and `maxConnections`

```
System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "true");
System.setProperty("http.maxConnections","600");
```

And then I start fetch html from internet with several threads things like:

```
protected static String content(URLConnection conn) throws IOException {
    try (InputStream in = getInputStream(conn)) {
        //bla bla bla...
        // get bytes from in
        return new String(bytes, charset);
    }
}
```

But I found when I run this procedure for a while (5-8 hours), target website (for test) is Established 760 connections?

So , should I and how can I close URLConnection manually ?

Comment: ... and you are not actually `close()`ing the input stream? That would be the first thing to do. And you should throttle concurrent requests for particular web sites as well; this is "Spidering 101" style basic thing to do, to limit load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never seen a way to close the connection explicitly using its API. However, you can set the connection read timeout using [`setReadTimeout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setReadTimeout%28int%29) method. This need to be set before the connection is made.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, you might try using a Socket/ServerSocket instead of URLConnection - with Sockets, you can close the socket when you so choose, and it gives you a more down-and-dirty control over when to open, close, read, and write to a connection. Check out the API:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html

Comment: Thank you , but this is too complicated to implement.